# Using Google Encoded Polyline Algorithm Format with Oracle Database

Tags: algorithm, oracle-dbms, oracle-spatial, encoding

Google's [Encoded Polyline Algorithm Format](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm) is implemented in several GI tools. PostGIS e.g. has [ST_AsEncodedPolyline](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsEncodedPolyline.html) and [ST_LineFromEncodedPolyline](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineFromEncodedPolyline.html) functions.

In contrast, Oracle Database has no corresponding functions. Neither in the Locator module, which is part of the regular license, nor in the Spatial&Graph extension.

**Is there an implementation of Google's polyline encoding algorithm for Oracle?**

[The algorithm is well documented](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm), but not trivial to implement because it uses some bit operations (which are part of nearly every programming language, but not of Oracle SQL resp. PL/SQL).

Comment: That is correct. Oracle does not offer this out of the box. Implementing it is doable via Java. Meaning that if a java library exists that performs that encoding, it is easy to load it into your Oracle database and invoke it via a PL/SQL wrapper.

Comment: What would you use this encoding for ? Would you store the geometries in the database in the encoded format ? Or would it be used as an exchange format - a bit like GeoJSON, GML, KML or WKT ?

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind yes, I would use it as an exchange format. Thanks for the hint to Java - I haven't used Java in Oracle yet, but maybe will have a look at this.

Comment: Let me know when you want to try the java approach. If you can find a java library that does the transformation from/to the Google encoding, I can take a look and try implementing it. The principle is to: (1) load the java library (the jar file) via a command line or PL/SQL procedure (2) write a static java class/method that invokes the methods exposed in the java library and load that in the database as well, and finally (3) write a PL/SQL wrapper that invokes the proper static methods.

Comment: It turns out that Oracle has implemented this transformation - only it is not available yet in any shipping version. Current thought is to include it in 20c.

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind good to hear!

Answer (score 0):

According to Albert Godfrind's comment: the feature is **planned for Oracle 20c**